# How do I get HTML element to load properly with Jasmine Karma?

Tags: jquery, html, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a couple of tests set up to see if jquery is returning my HTML objects. Something seems to be wrong with how my karma.conf file is pulling in the html files.

I tried using variables from the JS files referenced in karma.conf.js and they all work fine in testing.

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser, order matters
    files: [
      './js/jquery.min.js',
      './*.js',
      {pattern: './*.html'},
      {pattern: './pages/*.html'},
      {pattern: './js/*.js'},      
      {pattern: './js/pages/*.js'},
      {pattern: './test/pages/*Spec.js'},
      {pattern: './test/*Spec.js'},
    ],
    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    preprocessors: {
        './js/pages/*.js': 'coverage',
        './js/main.js': 'coverage',
    },
     // test results reporter to use
    reporters: [
        'progress', 
        'coverage'
    ],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    // start these browsers
    browsers: ['Chrome_without_sandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_without_sandbox: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--headless',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
        ] // without thisit fails under Docker
      }
    },
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity,
    plugins: [
        'karma-coverage',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
    ],
    coverageReporter: {
         type : 'html',
        dir : 'coverage/'
    },
    // proxy for AJAX requests
    proxies: {
      '': 'http://localhost'
    },
   });
};
```

snippet of main.html

```
<label class="inline">PORT 4:</label>
<input id="portFour" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-width="86" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
```

mainSpec.js

```
describe("see if it's checked", function () {
  it('should be checked', function() {
    expect($("#portFour").prop("checked")).toBe(true);
  });
});

describe("see if it exists", function () {
  it('should be true', function() {
    expect($("#portFour").length > 0).toBe(true);
  });
});

describe('see if it's defined', function() {
  it('should be defined', function() {
    expect($("#portFour")).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

The first two assertion fails (results were undefined and false, respectively) but the last one passes. How do I get it to reference the html elements properly?

Comment: To help debug, would you mind adding this line to one of your failing specs before the assertion and see what gets printed in your console:   console.log({'what': 'failing test #1', 'elem': $("#portFour") }), or something like that. It might be helpful to see what kind of object it's returning to you -- for instance, you might want to try accessing $("#portFour")[0].length instead of $("#portFour").length.

Comment: INFO: Object{what: 'failing test #1', elem: jQuery{}}

Comment: Interesting. If it's an empty object, I'm wondering if either jQuery really isn't loaded OR if the test is running before the page loads fully. Either way, I think that your passing test is probably passing as a false-positive in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Okay, so after commenting with you and thinking some more, I'm expanding my answer.

I think the issue is partly due to a confusion between types of testing. Karma is a test runner primarily for Unit Tests. However, the kinds of tests you're wanting to run (checking for an element being visible on a page, or if a checkbox is checked) sound more like "Acceptance" or "End-to-End" tests, where you test a web page or app from the perspective of a user.

---

**Unit VS Acceptance Testing**

I suggest you ditch Karma for this, and use some other tools built for these kinds of tests. Specifically, you'll need these tools for acceptance testing (there will be alternatives for some):

1. Assertion Library (Jasmine)
   This is where you get all the syntax for things like "describe()", "it()", etc. It's the syntax for writing a test case and the set of things you can test, such as toBeEqual(), toBe(), toBeDefined(), etc.
2. NPM, NodeJS (I'm just choosing Node since it's easy and you could easily setup Node development testing too without much trouble)
3. Selenium/Browser Pretender (WebDriver for Node/JS apps, or ProtractorJS)
   This is the set of methods for interacting with pages in your tests. You'd look in the docs here for ways to find elements, wait for page loads, check for an element being visible, etc. [WebDriverIO](http://webdriver.io/guide.html)

To try to help illustrate this, I've made up a small JSFiddle that uses Jasmine and runs acceptance tests on your HTML code and prints the results once jQuery is loaded into the page with the other files (2 of your tests then pass).

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gjonueax/)

**HTML**

```
<label class="inline">PORT 4:</label>
<input id="portFour" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-width="86" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
```

**JS**

```
describe('a suite', function() {
    it('is a spec', function() {
        expect(true).toEqual(true);
    });
});

describe("The Checkbox", function () {

  it('should be checked', function() {
    expect($("#portFour").prop("checked")).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should be visible', function() {
    expect($("#portFour").length > 0).toBe(true);
  });

  it('can be defined by jQuery', function() {
    expect( $("#portFour") ).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

Comment: The last assertion (which checks if the element is defined) returned true though. I downloaded the non-minified version and got the same results. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Downvoted this answer for the following reason: Just because a unit test involves the validating HTML markup does not automatically make it an "end to end" or "user acceptance" test.  Nor does it exclude the tests from being a "unit test" just because it involves validating the markup behavior in concert with the JS component.